# In place editing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, best-in-place

I receive an error wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3) how can i apply it in a each loop ? I want to be able to edit it inplace in an each loop

```
  <%= best_in_place s.message %>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
```

**user.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
 $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

version best_in_place 3.1.1

OR

Is there a more better way of implementing an inplace editing

Comment: What are you trying to do?, you're passing just a value that could be a placeholder.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma i want to be able to edit the message in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
best_in_place(object, field, opts = {})
```

See the arguments the [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/blob/332eda290cb133683a99d43a30321bab27d85e70/lib/best_in_place/helper.rb#L3) method expects to receive. You're passing only one.

- `object` means an object or specific record.
- `field` is the attribute which to edit - in your case it could be `message`.
- `options` all the [options](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#best_in_place) it accepts.

Most probably you need something like:

```
<%= best_in_place @object, :message, as: :input %>
```

Comment: it returns the error undefined method `message'  it seems that :message is seen as a method ? 
i placed it outside the each loop <% @admin.each do |s| %>
<%= best_in_place @admin, :message, as: :input %>

Comment: What's the value of `@admin`?

Comment: @admin = Message.where(id: current_user)

Comment: Whenever you use `where` it returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation`, that's why, that kind of object doesn't have a method called `message`, you need to access the single object, as I've pointed _`object` means an object or specific record_. To check, try using `Message.where(id: current_user).first`.

Comment: Last question Is there any way i can place it in an each loop ?

Comment: I placed Message.where(id: current_user).first but now I get an error ofundefined method `message_path'

Comment: Of course yes, if you use where, it get's you a "set" of records which you can iterate. Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/vnhnhm/aece7bd088e450d17a997d8a195f9f0e), of course you can adapt it to your code, and the query in the controller.

Comment: I placed Message.where(id: current_user).first but now I get an error of undefined method `message_path problem of installation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156907/discussion-between-sebastian-palma-and-rother-jon).